# Are windows events handled sequentially or in parallel?

Tags: windows, multithreading, wxwidgets

I always thought that the events in an applications event queue were handles sequentially, but because of some otherwise hardly to explain misbehaviour in an application of mine, I need to ask: Can it happen that eventhandlers for different events are runnung in parallel? I am using `wxWidgets` and its event handling mechanism, in case that matters; also I do use multithreading for other purpose, with a "main" and a "worker" thread (`wxThreadHelper`) and was under the impression that the usual events would only be handled by the - single - main thread - and that single-threadedly. Can someone confirm one way or the other?

**EDIT:** I am talking about what is a *message* in Windows parlance (`WM_PAINT`, `WM_KEYDOWN` etc.) , but I talked about *events* because of the wxWidgets naming convention (`wxPaintEvent` etc.). Sorry for the confusion. In fact it may even matter that I use wxWidgets mechanisms instead of Windows own; e.g. maybe wxWidgets pops Messages singlethreadedly and dispatches them to OnFoobarHandler() multithreadedly or vice versa - I don't know (though I thought I did ).

Comment: Are you talking about messages? [Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655.aspx) are only used to signal when things happen, what those things are is purely an application layer decision.

Comment: I think he's talking about windows messages (i.e. GetMessage, DispatchMessage, PostMessage, SendMessage, etc...)

Comment: Hagen - Before I post a long answer, can you clarify what you mean by event queue and post a relevant code sample?  You can always called GetThreadId() API to figure out which thread your callbacks are occurring on.

Comment: In certain situations events can be processed in a re-entrant way. That is indeed dangerous and can look like real concurrency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events are only handled in the main, UI thread. Only it has an event loop and all the handlers are called from it and hence execute on the same thread.

There is no magic.

Comment: Well, there *was* magic in the sense of Arthur C. Clarke, until I found my mistake: It happened that a function call caused a `wxASSERT`, which by default presents a dialog to the user. But my program runs as a service, hence without GUI. It seems that in such a situation, the event handler function is exited from without a catchable exception and without(!) deleting objects from the stack; this is what originally made it look to me like two events being handled concurrently. Overriding `OnAssertFailure` in my app class cured the problem (and allowed finding the true cause of the `wxASSERT`).

Comment: This seems very suspicious to me. Perhaps something (inside or outside your code) eats Windows (i.e. SEH) exceptions. Because the default assert handler either returns normally (e.g. in release build with assert dialogs disabled) or dies (e.g. if it's reentered), so it can't explain what you're seeing.